# laravel many to many relation sync "Illegal offset type"

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am new to larvel 5.6 and trying to learn it.
I have the following code:

```
$gr = group::create([
          'book_id' => $book_id,
      ]);
$owner = Book::where('id', $book_id)->pluck('user_id');
$id1 = Auth::user()->id;
$gr->users()->sync([$id1 => ['last_seen_id' => -1], $owner => ['last_seen_id' => -1]]);
```

in the pivot table group_user I have one extra column which is last_seen_id but I get the error :

> "Illegal offset type"

so what I tried is to change the code to the following:

```
$gr = group::create([
          'book_id' => $book_id,
      ]);
$owner = Book::where('id', $book_id)->pluck('user_id');
$gr->users()->sync([Auth::user()->id => ['last_seen_id' => -1], $owner => ['last_seen_id' => -1]]);
```

But I keep getting the same error, please kindly help me to understand what is wrong and how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the `$owner` represent the object, and by you're code, it looks like you're trying to get it to be an array, both types cannot be used as an array index, which you have in your last line.
Maybe you're trying to get only one owner id, so what I'm guessing you need to get is

```
$owner = Book::where('id', $book_id)->first();
if(!empty($owner)) {
    $owner = $owner->user_id;
} else {
    throw new \Exception();
}
```

Comment: The given example will throw NullPointerException if the book with the $book_id does not exist. You should always check that you have an object returned.

Comment: I know, this was just an example, he could have done something like $owner = Book::where('id', $book_id)->first(); if($owner) { $owner = $owner->user_id; } else { throw new Exception; }, just wanted to point out that ->pluck('') method returns an object Collection which cannot be used as an array index.